# Qt: Detect Double-Click with Modkey (Shift, CTRL, etc.)

Tags: qt, mouseevent, qtgui, modifier-key

How can I detect whether a double click on a QWidget (QStatusBar, in my case) occured while a modifier key was held down?

I can overload `void QWidget::mouseDoubleClickEvent ( QMouseEvent * event )` to get the double click, but how can I sure whether the widget receives the key events when it might not have the focus?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer:

`QMouseEvent` is derived from `QInputEvent` and that has a method called `modifiers()`:

From the [Qt documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qinputevent.html#modifiers):

> Returns the keyboard modifier flags that existed immediately before the event occurred.

Comment: did you actually test this approach, Qt Doc states aswell that these are not 100% trustable.

Comment: Yes, I have an event filter installed on a `QWidget` which casts the event into `QMouseEvent *` and tests two modifier keys in case the event is of type `QEvent::MouseButtonDblClick. Works like a charm...

Answer (score 1):

If you have a SLOT for your (Mouse)Event or Signal, you can test the modifiers there:

```
Qt::KeyboardModifiers modifiers  = QApplication::queryKeyboardModifiers ();
if(modifiers.testFlag( Qt::ControlModifier )){
  qDebug() << "CTRL was hold when this function was called";
}
else{
  qDebug() << "CTRL wasn't hold";
}

//SHIFT    = Qt::ShiftModifier
//CTRL     = Qt::ControlModifier
//ALT      = Qt::AltModifier
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to add More information
in your QWidget you only need to override this method

```
protected:
    void mouseDoubleClickEvent(QMouseEvent *event);
```

cheers